# Iterator giving NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

```
public static void mouseAction(String action, int x, int y) {
    for (Iterator<ArrayList<GameObject>> j = obj.iterator(); j.hasNext();) {
        ArrayList<GameObject> g = j.next();
        for (Iterator<GameObject> i = g.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            if (i.next() instanceof MouseInteractable) {
                switch (action) {
                case "click":
                    ((MouseInteractable) i.next()).onClick(x, y);
                    break;
                case "move":
                    ((MouseInteractable) i.next()).onMove(x, y);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason is giving me an no such element exception. 
When I replace the iterators with a normal for loop it works perfectly. But in some cases I need to edit the objects while iterating them (on mouse click), therefore I need an iterator but yeah not working...

Answer (score 0):

Each call to `i.next ()` advances the iterator. You should only call it once inside the loop and store the returned value in a variable in order to reuse it, similar to what you already do with the `j` iterator.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `next()` twice inside the inner loop. You should do something like this:

```
public static void mouseAction(String action, int x, int y) {
    for (Iterator<ArrayList<GameObject>> j = obj.iterator(); j.hasNext();) {
        ArrayList<GameObject> g = j.next();
        for (Iterator<GameObject> i = g.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            GameObject gameObject = i.next();
            if ( gameObject instanceof MouseInteractable) {
                mouseObject = (MouseInteractable) gameObject;
                switch (action) {
                case "click":
                    mouseObject.onClick(x, y);
                    break;
                case "move":
                    mouseObject.onMove(x, y);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```